# How to autorefresh calendar(ical) in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, auto-update, icalendar

Is there any property in the 'iCal' standard which can automatically update calendar?
For example,
UPDATEURL: mysite.com/myFile.ics
UPDATEFREQUENSY:1DAY

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing in the standard specifying the update rate.
However Microsoft has a custom way to control the update frequency:  with a custom calendar property: X-PUBLISHED-TTL (see [microsoft msdn calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178699%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx))

> 2.1.3.1.1.15 Property: X-PUBLISHED-TTL
>
> Brief Description: Specifies a suggested iCalendar file download frequency for clients and servers with sync capabilities.

however note that this property being custom will be ignored by other calendars

Answer (score 1):

Such properties have been proposed in this [draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daboo-icalendar-extensions-05):

> ###5.4.  URL Property
>
> This specification modifies the definition of the "URL" property to
> allow it to be defined on an iCalendar object.  The following
> additions are made to the definition of this property.
>
> Purpose:  This property specifies a URL from where the calendar data
> was retrieved or where it can be refreshed.
>
> Conformance:  This property can be specified once in an iCalendar
> object.
>
> Description:  This property specifies a URL identifying the source of
> the calendar data and a location from where updates can be retrieved.
>
> ###5.6.  REFRESH-INTERVAL Property
>
> Property Name:  REFRESH-INTERVAL
>
> Purpose:  This property specifies a suggested minimum interval for
> polling for changes of the calendar data from the original source of
> that data.
>
> Value Type:  DURATION - no default
>
> Property Parameters:  IANA and non-standard property parameters can be
> specified on this property.
>
> Conformance:  This property can be specified once in an iCalendar
> object.
>
> Description:  This property specifies a positive duration that gives a
> suggested minimum polling interval for checking for updates to the
> calendar data.  The value of this property SHOULD be used by calendar
> user agents to limit the polling interval for calendar data updates to
> the minimum interval specified.
>
> Format Definition:  This property is defined by the following
> notation:
>
> ```
>    refresh      = "REFRESH-INTERVAL" refreshparam
>                     ":" dur-value CRLF
>                     ;consisting of a positive duration of time.
>
>    refreshparam = *(
>                    ;
>                    ; The following is REQUIRED,
>                    ; but MUST NOT occur more than once.
>                    ;
>                    (";" "VALUE" "=" "DURATION") /
>                    ;
>                    ; The following is OPTIONAL,
>                    ; and MAY occur more than once.
>                    ;
>                    (";" other-param)
>                    ;
>                    )
> ```
>
> Example:  The following is an example of this property:
>
> `REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:P1W`

Note that this is still just a proposal. I don't think the new properties are currently supported by any calendar software.